# The problem is that selecting the image is mandatory in firebase swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a button to send and save the data in firebase

data is : TextFiled and TextView and Color and Image

The problem is in the picture

I can not perform the transmission without selecting the image

I want to make it optional

This Button Code :

```
@IBAction func SendBtn(_ sender: Any) {

    if let profileImage = SelecSubStorge , let  profileIMG = profileImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1) {
        
        let udidImage = NSUUID().uuidString
        let storeg = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: "gs://myproduct-744cb.appspot.com").child(udidImage)
        
        storeg.putData(profileIMG, metadata: nil) { metaDate, error in
            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
                return
            } else {
                storeg.downloadURL { url, error in
                    let imgSub = url?.absoluteString
                    
                    let cgColor = self.ColorIsColor!.cgColor
                    self.labelColor = CIColor(cgColor: cgColor).stringRepresentation
                    
                    let ref = Database.database().reference()
                    let sub = ref.child("Sub")
                    let udid = sub.childByAutoId().key
                    let setRef = sub.child(udid!)
                    let value = ["sub": self.subjectLB.text , "detiles" : self.detilesTextview.text , "ImgSub" : imgSub , "SubID" : udid , "Color" : self.labelColor , "Alignment" : self.data0 , "sizeFont" : self.SliderSize ] as [String : Any]
                    setRef.setValue(value) { error, ref in
                        if error != nil {
                            print(error?.localizedDescription)
                        } else {
                            
                            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Done", message: "Done Send", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

                                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))

                                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                            
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where is the problem and how can I make it optional?

Comment: You've kinda coded yourself into a corner; the code flow, as it, forces an image to be selected before any data is written (which is the problem). You need to change the code flow - you only need to run that code *if* an image is selected, so just a if statement -  `if image is selected then call func storeg.putData else call func setRef.setValue(value) (which is the data without the image)`. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to put a placeholder image in the design to be like this:

[image]

Try this:

create a variable for the image:

```
var profileImage: UIImage?
```

Then create the function below:

```
func imageFromInitials(first: String?, last: String?, withBlock: @escaping (_ image: UIImage) -> Void) {
    
    var string: String!
    var size = 36
    
    if first != nil && last != nil {
        string = String(first!.first!).uppercased() + String(last!.first!).uppercased()
    } else {
        string = String(first!.first!).uppercased()
        size = 72
    }
    
    let lblNameInitialize = UILabel()
    lblNameInitialize.frame.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    lblNameInitialize.textColor = .white
    lblNameInitialize.font = UIFont(name: lblNameInitialize.font.fontName, size: CGFloat(size))
    lblNameInitialize.text = string
    lblNameInitialize.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    lblNameInitialize.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    lblNameInitialize.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(lblNameInitialize.frame.size)
    lblNameInitialize.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    
    let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    
    withBlock(img!)
}
```

In your function, you will do this:

```
var value = ["sub": self.subjectLB.text , "detiles" : self.detilesTextview.text , "SubID" : udid , "Color" : self.labelColor , "Alignment" : self.data0 , "sizeFont" : self.SliderSize ] as [String : Any]


  if profileImage == nil {
            imageFromInitials(first: self.subjectLB.text!, last: self.detilesTextview.text!) { (imageInitial) in
                
                let myImage = imageInitial.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)
                let finalImage = myImage?.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
                value["ImgSub"] = finalImage
            }
        }
else {
      //use the code you used to put the image
}
```

Comment: can you add this function: SelecSubStorge to the code?

Comment: var SelecSubStorge : UIImage?

Comment: extension ViewSendQuestion : UIImagePickerControllerDelegate , UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        
        if let SelectedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {
            imgSub.image = SelectedImage
            SelecSubStorge = SelectedImage
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    
}

Comment: could you make it an array with one item only ?

Comment: How do you get an array on a single image?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233573/discussion-between-menaim-and-bdriii).

Comment: Did not succeed

Comment: check the updated answer again, It will work with you

Comment: Thank you, you explained a lot to me I will try when I get up

Answer (score 0):

extension ViewSendQuestion : UIImagePickerControllerDelegate , UINavigationControllerDelegate {
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

```
    if let SelectedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {
        imgSub.image = SelectedImage
        SelecSubStorge = SelectedImage
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}